# How to replace linux os from within itself

Tags: linux, grub2, virtual-machine

I am using a Nebula server from where it is only possible to install Ubuntu 16.04 with the kernel 4.4.0-210-generic.

I wish to install a newer version of linux on my instance.

### Virtualization

I have tried making a virtual machine from within Ubuntu, (with libvirt) but I get the message:

```
ERROR Host does not support any virtualization options
```

However, when I check `lscpu` I get:

```
Virtualisation:        VT-x
```

### Using grub and another disk with installable ISO

So then I was thinking that I could try to replace the whole operating system manually from within itself.

I have the power to create new drives for the instance.

So I added a 16GB drive

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   16G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  2,9G  0 part 
└─sda2   8:2    0  3,9M  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  364K  0 rom  
vda    253:0    0  500G  0 disk 
└─vda1 253:1    0  500G  0 part /
```

and made it an Ubuntu disk with

```
dd if=ubuntu20.04.iso of=/dev/sda
```

However, I don't have the power to change the drive to boot from.

- My "old" os drive has the id 0
- my new Ubuntu ISO drive has the id 2

the Nebula configuration is hard-coded to boot from id 0 and I cannot change it.

I checked my system on the `/boot` directory and I found that the boot system is GRUB.

So I checked the version

```
grub-install --version
```

And it seems to be Grub2

```
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.32
```

I was wondering if it is possible to tell grub to boot into my ubuntu20.04 disk and then install over the disk with id0 called `vda`?

### Replacing the OS by simply replacing files in the system.

If it is not possible to run an installer, then I was thinking about just replacing the kernel and all the operating system files manually. However, I am pretty sure the system will crash if I replace files that the system I currently using -- but maybe there is a way to do it in a correct order.

Comment: Can't you just upgrade the Ubuntu 16.04 to a newer version?

Comment: Linux OS ? What do you mean ? The Linux kernel + minimal set of basic procs to build from sources or whatever bloated binary distro based on the Linux kernel ? First option is just easy, second ? I cannot tell, I never tried.

Comment: Replacing a file that is in use is fine. When you remove a file, it is not deleted, until in is no longer in a directory and no longer in use.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading Ubuntu from a version to a newer is possible at the command line

The main tasks are `sudo apt install update-manager-core` this install the updater. Then `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

See https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04-lts-using-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't update your Ubuntu install as another answer suggests, you can point GRUB at your install disk by grabbing its disk identifier (in the form of `(hdX, msdosY)` or `(hdX,gptY)` and manually creating a menuentry in `/boot/grub/grub-cfg` [1]

```bsh
menuentry "New Ubuntu Install Disk" {
          search --set=root --label GRUB --hint hdX,msdosY
          linux /path/to/vmlinuz #likely in /boot/
          initrd /path/to/initrd #also likely in /boot/
}
```

Also maybe you have more control over boot order than you realise: `efibootmgr` ([docs](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Efibootmgr)) can be used to alter boot devices manually.

Alternatively, you can reboot and enter the GRUB command line manually (with `c`), and boot into your installer from there (this is a one-time endeavor though). Instructions on how to do that [here](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux/)

[1] https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config